# How to get the whole pinia state object?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I'm trying to have a getter that return all state properties of my pinia store.

```
export const useFilterStore = defineStore('filterStore', {
    state : () : FilterState => ({
        variables:[] as string[],
        categories:[] as string[]
    }),


    getters: {
        getFilters: (state) => state
    },
    actions : {}
  });
```

Doing it this way , getFilters references itself generating circular reference on different situation, as illustrated in this component

```
import { useFilterStore } from './store/filter-store.js'
export default {
  name: 'App',

  setup() {
    const filter = useFilterStore()
    JSON.stringify(filter.getFilters)  --> cyclic object value
  }
}
```

Is there a way to set up a getter for the whole state object directly?

Comment: External links may be unavailable. Please, provide all relevant code in the question. The question doesn't have the context without it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getFilters` doesn't serve a good purpose. `state` is the whole store, not just state data, accessing `state.getFilters` results in a recursion.

It should be:

```
 JSON.stringify(filter.$state)
```